# Did China receive blue prints of the IAI Lavi jet from Israel?

Tags: china, israel

On the Internet, it is frequently found that the Chinese J-10 fighter jet evolved from the Israeli IAI Lavi project in that either China obtained the blueprints or received direct technical assistance from Israel regarding this project.

- [Why China Looked To Israel's Lavi Jet For Its J-10 'Vigorous Dragon'](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/reboot/why-china-looked-israels-lavi-jet-its-j-10-vigorous-dragon-160931)
- [Pakistan Purchases Chinese Jets Based on Scrapped Israeli Lavi Fighter](https://www.haaretz.com/world-news/asia-and-australia/2022-01-05/ty-article/pakistan-purchases-chinese-jets-based-on-scrapped-israeli-lavi-fighter/0000017f-f71b-d887-a7ff-ffffa08e0000)

On the other hand, there are some disagreements -

- [1979 China's J-10 wood model preceded Israeli Lavi program](https://defenceforumindia.com/threads/1979-chinas-j-10-wood-model-preceded-israeli-lavi-program.68594/)
- [Wikipedia.org > Chengdu_J-10 > Disputed_origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengdu_J-10#Disputed_origins)

Did China receive blue prints of the IAI Lavi jet from Israel?

Comment: the Wikipedia article states that IAI Lavi was "a project based on the F-16". this is incorrect. the Lavi predates the F-16. the Lavi was based on French MIrage

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, not true. IAI Nesher and Kfir were based on French Mirages. Lavi looks nothing similar to Mirage.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any statement in here that could be declared true or false. Designing a fighter jet is massively complicated and of course every new design is based on and inspired by various previous designs. Maybe the makers of the Lavi jet gave some support to the designers of the J-10. That would at least in principle be answerable but whether the Chinese looked at a Lavi jet or not is not a meaningful question to me.

Comment: @quarague, edited the question.

Comment: Could you quote exactly what the claim is, rather than have users read four articles and try to guess? I may have missed it, but the articles don't seem to mention blueprints.